# Base server not getting internet connectivity but guest vm's getting internet connectivity

Tags: linux, network-interface

I had a Linux Ubuntu 14 server and on that server I install virtual box and created two VMs.

Issue is that Vms Are getting internet connectivity but the linux ubuntu server is not getting internet connectivity . I am not getting how it's possible that without getting internet connectivity at host guest are getting connectivity.

Comment: Please edit your question and add more details.  Nobody can see your configuration, so you need to post it on here so that we can at least try to help.  You've not said what the error is when you try to connect to the internet - "not getting internet connectivity" is quite broad!

Answer (score 0):

Does your server have Iptable rules ? 
Can try `iptable -F`.

If your VM's are configured with a direct access to the network, it's possible that they are able to connect to the internet while your host machine can't.